# Classify all probability spaces

Tags: measure-theory

There is supposed to be some theorem like the following, maybe with an extra condition or two:

All probability spaces are isomorphic to a disjoint union of the following spaces:

1. $[0,\ell] , \mathcal{B}, \mu$, where is $0 \leq \ell \leq 1$, and $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure, and,
2. an at most countable set $C$ with the discrete topology and the $\sigma$-algebra being the power set of $C$, and a positive measure $\nu$ on it such that $\nu (C) = 1-\ell$.

I would like to have a free-of-cost online source where I can find a proof of this statement. I think that the book of Royden contains a proof; unfortunately I am unable to access neither Royden nor a library at the moment.

Comment: Is this the result you want? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space#Standard_probability_space

Comment: Yes, that is the one. I mean, with some conditions(atom-free?) any probability space is a standard probability space.

Comment: *Any* is too many :) The result in Royden says that a finite Borel measure on a *complete, separable metric space* is isometric to a standard probability space.